# NSTimer Lag - iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nstimer, lag

I made a game that uses many timers throughout the code. However the timer has to deal with many tasks in such a small amount of time which leads to the problem where there is lag in my game. For example, my timer runs at an interval of (0.05) and it needs to draw and update many of the images on the screen. Is there any way I can distribute the work flow so that the program runs much smoother?

Thanks

Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an `NSThread` instead of an `NSTimer`. I have had more success in this area using NSThread because it runs on an independant thread and is not fired off your main ui thread. In the loop for the thread sleep it for 1/20 (your 0.05) of a second. Because the thread is not  running on the UI thread all of its tasks should not slow your UI down. However beacsue it is not running on the UI you will have to call `performSelectorOnMainThread` to get the UI to update from this background thread. I put a lock on my update method (a simple boolean) that says if the last ui update has not happened, just skip this one. then if im running out of processing time i just drop a frame or two here and there. I also do a lot of checking to see if anything has actually changed before i redraw.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: Ditch NSTimer.

Move your redrawing code to a single method, then use `CADisplayLink`. The issue with using your `NSTimer` approach is that everything is being redrawn too fast or too slow for the screen. By using CADisplayLink, you can synchronize your redraw code to the screen refresh rate. All you need to do then is touch up your code so that it can deal with not being called at a specific time.

And yes, check to make sure you don't need to redraw as Aran Mulholland said above. Just make sure the checks don't take as long as a redraw.

And remember to optimize your code. A lot. Use ivars to access objects, but the whole property (self.myObject =) to set your objects.